# How to show some content after each 5 iteration of ngFor in angular 8 project?

Tags: typescript, iteration, slice, angular8, ngfor

Gues someone can help me. My aim is to show some content after each 5 iterations of the ngFor. 
I tried to used the slice but cannot actually control what happen after the iterations.   Need help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of array; let i = index">
{{ element }}
<div *ngIf="i > 0 && (i+1)%5 === 0">Each 5</div>
```